# Re-fill same div in Vue using v-for

Tags: vue.js, populate

I think this should be a basic concept of Vue, but as I'm new, I don't know quite well how to get what I'm trying.

I'm able to populate a div with information gotten from a DB query using a V-for.

But I would like to do is to re-use the same div over and over, iterating over a click (it is a survey what I'm trying to do, answer a question, then click, and you have the next question in the same screen). As for now, my div repeats X times on screen, this is not the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have something like this

```
<div v-for="question in questions">
 {{question}}
</div>
```

You can change it to something like this

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(q, index) in questions" v-show="currentQuestion == index">
   {{q}}
   <span @click="currentQuestion++">Next</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and your data should be something like this

```
data: {
 questions: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,],
 currentQuestion: 1
}
```

Indexes in `v-for` start at 1 in vue.

Notes:

- You can use `v-show` instead of `v-if`, the difference is that `v-if` removes the tag from the DOM and `v-show` only change the value of the `display` property.
- You should read more about conditional [rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

Comment: Yes, this work wonderfully, thanks a lot for the help. I didn't know about v-show.